# How to create screenshot of every page on website

Tags: web-services, screenshot

Hello I found many programs which capture screenshot of the website, but I need a program which will 'click' all of the links on th site and give me sceenshots of every single page not only current. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying a https://www.screenshotmachine.com/ ? It seems to be what you're looking for.